# What is the proper way to import a custom java package located elsewhere in your projects directory structure?

Tags: java, import, package

Example Directory Structure

```
project/sameDir1/sameDir2/packagea
project/sameDir1/sameDir2/diffDirB1/diffDirB2/packageb
```

packagea contains Methods.java and begins with

```java
package packagea;
public class Methods {
```

packageb contains Test.java and begins with

```java
package packageb;
import packagea.Methods;
public class Test {
```

When attempting to compile Test.java

```sh
Test.java:2: error: package packagea does not exist
```

What is the proper way to import a custom java package located elsewhere in your projects directory structure?

Comment: please write the folder where you run compiler and command which you use to compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it as follows:

```
package sameDir1.sameDir2.packagea;

public class Methods {
```

and

```
package sameDir1.sameDir2.diffDirB1.diffDirB2.packageb;

import sameDir1.sameDir2.packagea.Methods;

public class Test {
```

### Demo:

**Methods.java:**

```
package sameDir1.sameDir2.packagea;

public class Methods {
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

**Test.java:**

```
package sameDir1.sameDir2.diffDirB1.diffDirB2.packageb;

import sameDir1.sameDir2.packagea.Methods;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Methods methods=new Methods();
        methods.hello();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
```

**Notes for the terminal window:**

```
mkdir project
cd project
vi Methods.java
vi Test.java
javac -d . *.java
tree
```

**Output:**

```
.
├── Methods.java
├── Test.java
└── sameDir1
    └── sameDir2
        ├── diffDirB1
        │   └── diffDirB2
        │       └── packageb
        │           └── Test.class
        └── packagea
            └── Methods.class
```

**Next:**

```
java sameDir1.sameDir2.diffDirB1.diffDirB2.packageb.Test
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
```

Comment: Following your example when attempting to compile Test.java I get the following error.
`diffDir/packageb/Test.java:2: error: package learn.packagea does not exist`

Comment: @JosephCrandall - It looks like you are trying to do all these from the Terminal window. I've added notes for Terminal window. Let me know in case of any further issue/doubt.

Comment: I decided my package structure was too complex and have simplified it to a single package. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

The package name should contain folder names starting from source root(the source root folder is the folder where you run compilation or which you specify as source root explicitly(javac with -sourcepath option)). 
In your case it can be one of the following options:

```
import project.sameDir1.sameDir1.packageA;
```

or

```
import sameDir1.sameDir1.packageA;
```

or

```
import sameDir1.packageA;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't do this from within your java source files; you do it in the tooling around it (so, your `java.exe` invocation, or your build script's configuration).

You have the 'source' side and the 'compiled' side. For both, there's the rule that class `MyClass` in package `mypkg1.mypkg2` must be in a file named `MyClass.java` / `MyClass.class`*, and that file must at least be in a directory named `mypkg2`, which must in turn be in a directory named `mypkg1`.

The directory that `mypkg1` is in is called a 'root'.

You can have multiple roots, that's not a problem, but the job of specifying roots is **not done from within your java code**.

For class files, this job falls to the classpath option. For example, if you have:

```
project/sameDir1/sameDir1/packageA/MyClass1.class
project/sameDir1/sameDir1/diffDirB1/diffDirB2/packageB/MyClass2.class
```

and you want `MyClass1` to be able to refer to `packageB.MyClass2` and have it work:

`java -cp project/sameDir1/sameDir1:project/sameDir1/sameDir1/diffDirB1/diffDirB2 packageA.MyClass1`

and it'll work great.

For the source side, you can also have different roots; you should be using a build tool, and none of the popular ones have any problem with it. IDEs, as well, have no problem with you specifying multiple source roots; for example, usually test files use a different root than the rest of the project.

*) non-public or inner classes need not be in a file named after itself; that distinction is not relevant here though.